# How to use Goose in Java Project

Tags: java, goose

How can i use Goose on a java project? I tested the online version of both boilerpipe and goose, and the last one it's way better but now it's developed in Scala.

I searched for the jar of previous version but can't find it (neither api). The last .jar i tried it's: goose-2.1.22. I imported it in my Ecplise project and tried with this code:

```
String url = "http://www.cnn.com/2010/POLITICS/08/13/democrats.social.security/index.html";
Goose goose = new Goose(new Configuration());
Article article = goose.extractContent(url);
System.out.println(article.cleanedArticleText());
```

But i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/ScalaObject
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at daweb.main(daweb.java:212)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.ScalaObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 13 more
```

Is it possible to use Goose without Scala?

Comment: were you able to find a solution ?

Answer (score 3):

You should add Scala Library to your buildpath

Answer (score 1):

There is a link provided in the issues page where you can find a .jar compiled for java use.
https://github.com/GravityLabs/goose/issues

```
import com.gravity.goose.*;


String url = "http://www.straitstimes.com/little-india-riot";
Goose goose = new Goose(new Configuration());
Article article = goose.extractContent(url);
System.out.println(article.cleanedArticleText());
```

This code works as a start.

Answer (score 1):

If you're managing your dependencies with Maven, you can just add [Goose](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.gravity/goose/2.1.22) to the dependencies section of your pom.xml and all of it's transitive dependencies will end up on the class path.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.gravity</groupId>
    <artifactId>goose</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.22</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `scala-library` jar to your classpath. If you are using Maven, add this dependency to your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.4</version>
</dependency>
```